# Wrong address when I do geth attach

Tags: mining, ethminer, geth-debugging

When I do geth attach I see the following:

```
$ ./geth attach
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.7.1-stable-05101641/linux-amd64/go1.9
coinbase: 0xe26fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdbe630202
at block: 0 (Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST)
datadir: /home/test/.ethereum
modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

> 

And the coinbase value I see is not my Wallet account on coinbase. Why is there some different address here?

Answer (score 1):

The term 'coinbase' is generally used in cryptocurrencies, and it doesn't refer to an account of the company with the same name.

In geth you can mine ethers, and the 'coinbase' is the address that will receive the block rewards when a block is mined. By default the first account you have created in geth will be the 'coinbase'.